# Spring rest controller not returning html

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot 1.5.2 and my spring rest controller looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

when I go to http://localhost:8090/assessment/ it reaches my controller but doesn't return my index.html, which is in a maven project under src/main/resources or src/main/resources/static. If I go to this url http://localhost:8090/assessment/index.html, it returns my index.html.  I looked at this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ and they use thymeleaf.  Do I have to use thymeleaf or something like it for my spring rest controller to return my view?

My application class looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.pkg.*"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I add the thymeleaf dependency to my classpath I get this error (500 response code)

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I guess I do need thymeleaf? I'm going to try and configure it properly now.

It works after changing my controller method to return index.html like this

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

I think thymeleaf or software like it allows you to leave off the file extension, not sure though.

Comment: For starters, make it a [`Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) instead of `RestController`

Comment: Now it still reaches the controller but I get a 404, whether the index.html is in src/main/resources or src/main/resources/static. http://localhost:8090/assessment/index.html still works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example would be something like this:

Your Controller Method with your route "assessment"

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/assessment")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Your Thymeleaf template in "src/main/resources/templates/index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 34):

RestController annotation returns the json from the method not HTML or JSP. It is the combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody in one. The main purpose of @RestController is to create RESTful web services. For returning html or jsp, simply annotated the controller class with @Controller.

Comment: I've changed it to @Controller and now I get a 404 but the request mapping is still working.  Do I need to add a view resolver bean? http:// localhost:8090/assessment/index.html still works

Comment: No thats what gives me the 404

Comment: that gives a 404.  I get a 500 after adding thymeleaf to my classpath

Comment: Now I'm getting a 304, its reaching my controller

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from configuration class.

> Spring MVC Auto-configuration provides static `index.html` support.
>
> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your
>   own `@Configuration` annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`.

Get more detail from [Spring MVC Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to "**Building a RESTful Web Service**" -> annotate your controller class with `@RestController` annotation if not annotate your controller class with `@Controller` class.

> When we use spring as **SpringMVC - @Controller**
>
> When we use spring as **SpringRESTfull Web Service - @RestController**

Use this link to read : [Spring Stereo Type](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after going from `@RestController` to `@Controller` and adding thymeleaf.
Be sure to use the correct one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As I previously had this one and it did not work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```