# Return "home" from Spring Boot controller method loads an empty page with the word "home" in it instead of home.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have a home.html Thymeleaf template and a controller endpoint method that returns "home" and instead of getting the template home.html served in the browser I get an empty page with the word "home" in it.

This is my controller:

```
      @PostMapping("/upload")
      public String handleFileUpload(Authentication authentication, 
      @RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file,
                               Model model) throws IOException {
      String userName = authentication.getName();
      User user = userService.getUser(userName);
      fileService.addFile(file, userName);
      return "home";
     }
```

And this is my home.html that lives under templates:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
    th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">

    <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-black">
    <div class="container">

        <div id="logoutDiv">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary float- 
          right" id="btn-logout">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="contentDiv" style="clear: right;">
            <nav style="clear: right;">
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-files- 
              tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-files" role="tab" aria- 
             controls="nav-files" aria-selected="true">Files</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-notes-tab" 
           data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-notes" role="tab" aria-c 
            controls="nav-notes" aria-selected="false">Notes</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-credentials- 
          tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-credentials" role="tab" 
            aria-controls="nav-credentials" aria- 
             selected="false">Credentials</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-files" 
         role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-files-tab">





                        <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                   th:action="@{/file/upload}" method="POST">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row" style="margin: 1em;">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <label for="fileUpload">Upload a New 
                                    File:</label>
                                  </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="file" class="form- 
                       control-file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn 
                          btn-dark" id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>


                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped" 
                             id="fileTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"> 
                                     </th>
                                    <th style="width: 80%" 
                                     scope="col">File Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                 <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
                 <a  class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                <th scope="row">ExampleFile.txt</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-notes" 
                   role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-notes-tab">
                    <button style="margin: 0.25em;" type="button" 
                      class="btn btn-info float-right" 
                       onclick="showNoteModal()">
                        + Add a New Note
                    </button>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped" 
                             id="userTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"> 
                                   </th>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" 
                                    scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th style="width: 60%" 
                                     scope="col">Description</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn 
                                     btn-success">Edit</button>
                                        <a class="btn btn- 
                                    danger">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <th scope="row">Example Note 
                                     Title</th>
                                    <td>Example Note Description </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="noteModal" tabindex="-1" 
      role="dialog" aria-labelledby="noteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" 
                       id="noteModalLabel">Note</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" 
                            data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times; 
                                   </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                                        <input type="hidden" 
                                     name="noteId" id="note-id">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="note-title" 
                                  class="col-form-label">Title</label>
                                            <input type="text" name= 
                                       "noteTitle" class="form-control" 
                                id="note-title" maxlength="20" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="note- 
                 description" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                                            <textarea class="form- 
                           control" name="noteDescription" id="note- 
                        description" rows="5" maxlength="1000" required> 
                                        </textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <button id="noteSubmit" 
                    type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn 
          btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn 
            btn-primary" onclick="$('#noteSubmit').click();">Save 
                        changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-credentials" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-credentials-tab">
                    <button style="margin: 0.25em;" type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" onclick="showCredentialModal()">
                        + Add a New Credential
                    </button>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped" th:object="${credentials}" id="credentialTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                                    <th style="width: 35%" scope="col">URL</th>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col">Username</th>
                                    <th style="width: 25%" scope="col">Password</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                <th scope="row">Example Credential URL</th>
                                <td>Example Credential Username</td>
                                <td>Example Credential Password</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="credentialModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="credentialModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="credentialModalLabel">Credential</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="credentialId" id="credential-id">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="credential-url" class="col-form-label">URL</label>
                                            <input type="text" name= "url" class="form-control" id="credential-url" maxlength="100" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="credential-username" class="col-form-label">Username</label>
                                            <input type="text" name= "username" class="form-control" id="credential-username" maxlength="30" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="credential-password" class="col-form-label">Password</label>
                                            <input type="text" name= "password" class="form-control" id="credential-password" maxlength="30" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <button id="credentialSubmit" type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#credentialSubmit').click();">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script th:src="@{/js/jquery-slim.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

    <!--For opening the note modal-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // For opening the note modal
        function showNoteModal(noteId, noteTitle, noteDescription) {
            $('#note-id').val(noteId ? noteId : '');
            $('#note-title').val(noteTitle ? noteTitle : '');
            $('#note-description').val(noteDescription ? noteDescription : '');
            $('#noteModal').modal('show');
        }

        // For opening the credentials modal
        function showCredentialModal(credentialId, url, username, password) {
            $('#credential-id').val(credentialId ? credentialId : '');
            $('#credential-url').val(url ? url : '');
            $('#credential-username').val(username ? username : '');
            $('#credential-password').val(password ? password : '');
            $('#credentialModal').modal('show');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

`

The login controller endpoint method has no issue returning the html template using the exact same structure and syntax:

```
       @GetMapping
       public String getHomePage() {
        return "home";
         }
```

I tried debugging the issue and I tried comparing against other online resources that seem to indicate there is nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Do you use @RestController of @Controller?

Comment: I use `@Controller` to the one that works, the one with the getHomePage() endpoint method, and `@RestController` with the one that does not! Please point me to a resource or a explain why that matters. Thank you, I so missed that!

Comment: Also relevant thread, now that I know that the controller annotation is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263667/spring-rest-controller-not-returning-html